# How to launch PhpStorm as another user?

Tags: ubuntu, phpstorm

I have installed PhpStorm as recommended on it's site:

```
sudo snap install phpstorm --classic
```

Now I can launch it from terminal using `phpstorm` command. But when I switch terminal user (with `su`) to another, I get:

```
phpstorm: command not found
```

What's wrong? How to launch PhpStorm from another user without switching current account? If I fully switch OS to that account, `phpstorm` command works ok.

Ubuntu 16.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `/snap/bin/phpstorm`.
Most probably /snap/bin is not added to root's $PATH.